# Which wood is best for cajon

Tags: instruments, percussion, cajon

I saw on www.amazon.in kadence cajon with variety of wood used in . But i am new to this so i need to know which wood is best the price is almost same for all wood.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52367/discussion-on-question-by-parassharma1990-which-wood-is-best-for-cajon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me, I did not pay attention to this detail, here is my reformulated answer.

You could buy a cajon with any wood, all would fulfill their role in your case.

But there are differences, I'm not just talking about sound quality. I see all aspects, manufacture, use, aesthetics, sound, durability, weight, etc ...

The MDS fulfills its role perfectly for being light (weight) and easy to work and you find everywhere. On the other hand MDS has lower resistance (water, impact, life time). MDF (Medium Density Fiberboard)* is used at all, personaly I don't recomend!
**Over time, the term MDF has become a generic name for any dry process fibre board.*

Two years ago I did some work with cajon playing in different ways with varying intensity and beat styles, I play two years avoiding the standard way of playing it, so we had opportunities to observe the quality of the cajon in the recordings, in order my opnion about the best performances:

- [Embuia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocotea_porosa)
- [Birch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch)
- [MDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-density_fibreboard)

Embuia is better option, more expensive in some places, but support more punches. It has a good durability and quality of sound!

Birch is my second good option!

Comment: Hi Gilberto - can you please add in the essential point: why

Comment: i.e. What effect does thin wood have on the sound? What does supporting more pressure do?

Comment: Smaller thickness (thin wood) XD
No difference in sound, I misunderstood the question, you are buying a Cajon, I thought you wanted buy the wood to create one!